# Python Code reading from port and storing in db gives error: #1062, Duplicate entry 1 for key PRIMARY

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Using pyserial, I am getting data from a sensor plugged into the USB port. I am trying to store that data, using MYSQLdb, into a database.

```
cur = db.cursor() 
cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE randomdata;")

if ser.isOpen():
    try:
        i = 1
        while 1:
            num = str(1)
            readserial = ser.readline()
            print readserial
            query="INSERT INTO randomdata(id,randomString)VALUES("+num+",'"+readserial+"');"
            cur.execute(query)
            db.commit()
            i+=1
            time.sleep(2)

            if (i >= 50):
                break
        ser.close()
    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)
else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

It will store one value in the database before showing the error message: "error communicating...: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'")"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It means that you already have this key in the DB table , so it cannot be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert twice a value with the same id.

Here your id is "1" each time.

Depending on what you want to do you will need to use UPDATE instead of INSERT if you want to keep always the same id (and thus keep only one value). Something like that (untested) :

```
"UPDATE randomdata SET randomString = " + readserial +" WHERE id = " + num
```

Or you want to store all your value and insert new entry each time, then you need to generate a new id each time (by using your `i` instead of `1` in the while loop).

Comment: Completely missed that one, meant to put i there instead... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
num = str(1)
```

which means num is always 1.

```
query="INSERT INTO randomdata(id,randomString)VALUES("+num+",'"+readserial+"');"
```

You insert 1 which is `num` as the ID  at each time which is your primary key. Then, you got the error.

Why don't you use `i` instead like this :

```
num = str(i)
```

Since you increase `i`, the ID will not be duplicated.